# How to substitute into regex named groups?

Tags: python, regex, logparser

I am trying to find a matching line in a logfile based on a regex , then check for the groups in it and report the expected and the actual line. 
The following examples show what exactly I am trying to do.

```
regex_str = '^.*name is (?P<name>[^.]*).*lives? in (?P<place>[^.]*).*$'
statement = 'My name is bala. I live in mumbai.'
statement2 = 'His name is bala. He lives in mumbai.'
ret = find_line([statement,'Garbage'],regex_str,name='bala',place='chennai')

ret == { 
'Expected' : 'My name is bala. I live in chennai.'
'Actual'   : 'My name is bala. I live in mumbai.'
'isMatched': False
}

ret = find_line([statement2,'Garbage'],regex_str,name='bala',place='chennai')

ret == { 
'Expected' : 'His name is bala. He lives in chennai.'
'Actual'   : 'His name is bala. He lives in mumbai.'
'isMatched': False
}

ret = find_line(['Garbage1','Garbage2'],regex_str,name='bala',place='chennai')

ret == {
'Expected' : '^.*name is (?P<name>[^.]*).*lives? in (?P<place>[^.]*).*$'
'Actual'   : '<No matching line>'
'isMatched': False
}

ret = find_line(['Garbage1',statement,'Garbage2',statement2],regex_str,name='bala',place='mumbai')

ret == {
'Expected' : 'My name is bala. I live in mumbai.'
'Actual'   : 'My name is bala. I live in mumbai.'
'isMatched': True
}
```

My real use-case is first argument will be a file_object. the find_line function will keep tailing the file until either a match is found(either correct or wrong) or for a fixed timeout.

I am looking for an implementation of `find_line` that will give the desired output.
Any suggestions / solutions?

Comment: In first case if `statement = 'His name is bala. He live in mumbai.'` then what should be `Expected` field value?

Comment: @DairT'arg Updated with expected value and corrected other example

Comment: @BrenBarn I am still thinking.. Couldn't think of a good solution.

Comment: @balki Still didn't got you well. You want regex matching except for named regex parameters?

Answer (score 1):

My straightforward attempt

```
import re
def find_line(lines,regex_str,**params):
    regex = re.compile(regex_str)
    for line in lines:
        m = regex.match(line)
        if m:
            actual = m.string
            groups = sorted (
                [(0,0,'')] +
                [(m.start(gname),m.end(gname),gname) for gname in params] +
                [(len(actual),0,'')])
            expected = ''
            for i in range(len(groups)-1):
                expected += actual[groups[i][1]:groups[i+1][0]]
                gname = groups[i+1][2]
                if gname: expected += params[gname]
            return {'Expected': expected, 'Actual': actual, 'isMatched' : expected == actual}
    return {'Expected': None, 'Actual': None, 'isMatched' : False}
```

problem here in case where match not found( example 3) . As we can see from examples "Expected" is result of transforming the mathed string. So if no string was mathed, no expected value can be formed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a close look at [re module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). In particular, there is [re.MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects) (you can obtain it as a result of `re.match(regex_str, statement)`) with various methods for working with matched groups content and positions.